# If UIButton is selected, unselect the other UIButton in Swift (Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I'm working on an app that makes me choose different colors for some LED's in an Arduino Uno. Now, I am a little stuck in the code.

If one button is selected, which is a color, the other button should be deselected because you can only have one color at a time. Please, take a look at the code below. The code below is a subclass which all the buttons have a connection to.

```
import UIKit

class ToggleTheButtons: UIButton {

// Buttons are all off on load.
var isOn = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
    initButton()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){

    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    initButton()

}

func initButton(){
    // Initializes the button.
    layer.borderWidth = 0.0

    addTarget(self, action: #selector(ToggleTheButtons.buttonPressed),    for: .touchUpInside)

}

// What happens when we press the buttons.
@objc func buttonPressed() {

    activateButton(bool: !isOn)

}

// Toggles button on and off.
func activateButton(bool: Bool) {

    isOn = bool

    // Ternary operator. true:false (Boolean is nodig)
    _ = bool ? (layer.borderWidth = 2.0) : (layer.borderWidth = 0.0)
    //        layer.borderColor = (borderColorOfTheButton as! CGColor)


}

}
```

Since I am still working on my skills you may find some weird code in here. Please give me any feedback on errors you find.

I am looking forward to reading your responses.

EDIT: I have linked my UIButtons through IBActions, screenshot below.
[image: Screenshot of main.storyboard]

Below you'll find the code for licht.swift. Here the buttons are linked.

```
import UIKit

class Licht: UIViewController {

// Link alle knoppen met de code. Check ToggleTheButtons.swift voor de     toggle functies. Misschien een IBAction.
//    @IBOutlet weak var redButton: ToggleTheButtons!

@IBAction func redButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}
@IBAction func orangeButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func yellowButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func greenButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func lightBlueButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func darkBlueButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func purpleButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func pinkButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}

@IBAction func whiteButton(_ sender: ToggleTheButtons) {
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    func databaseConnection() {

        // Hier komt de connectie met de database. 

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Sincerely,

Frank.

Comment: How you assign this class to UIButton? From storyboard or code?

Comment: @JD. I have added the answer above.

Comment: Possibly you can use logic of Radio button. If i am not wrong you need the logic exactly like that. If u want my logic of implementing the radio button. please ask for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
- Set tag to all UIButton (1 - 9)
- Set borderWidth to all Buttons
- Connect all the button to the below mentioned IBAction

@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for button in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if button is UIButton {
             // Do whatever you want
             button.layer.borderColor = button.tag == sender.tag ? UIColor.blue.cgColor : UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

It's done

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with setting a tag to all UIButtons? Should the @IBAction be put in the subclass .swift file?

Comment: You can set the button tag value by "button.tag = 1" or There is an option in Attribute inspector in Stroyboard

Comment: Cool. So all the buttons should be linked to the same action with the same name?

Comment: Yes, same IBAction function

Comment: Cool. This worked! Now on to making the text change on button click :)

Answer (score 4):

According to your storyboard layout design and your requirement, I've completely different solution for you.

You can use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) with single cell selection permission only, if you can manage your design (grid 3 x 3) using collection view.

Set you buttons inside [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell) and handle its selection/deselection using [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) methods:

#### [collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview)

Tells the delegate that the item at the specified index path was selected.

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

#### [collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618035-collectionview)

Tells the delegate that the item at the specified path was deselected.

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

**Try this and see:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonsCell
        cell.button.isSelected = cell.isSelected  // handle button selection 
        // or for your toggle button
        // cell.button.isOn = cell.isSelected
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ButtonsCell
        cell?.button.isSelected = true  // select button

        // or for your toggle button
        // cell.button.isOn = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ButtonsCell
        cell?.button.isSelected = false  // deselect button

        // or for your toggle button
        // cell.button.isOn = false
    }

}

// UICollectionViewCell class with your button
class ButtonsCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: ToggleTheButtons!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a switch statement:

```
switch sender {
    case firstButton:
        firstButton.isSelected = true
        secondButton.isSelected = false
        thirdButton.isSelected = false
    case secondButton:
        secondButton.isSelected = true
        firstButton.isSelected = false
        thirdButton.isSelected = false
    case thirdButton:
        thirdButton.isSelected = true
        secondButton.isSelected = false
        thirdButton.isSelected = false
    default:
        print("Error")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create an array of `ToggleTheButtons`:

```
@IBOutlet var toggleButtons : [ToggleTheButtons]!
```

and connect all buttons to that collection.
When a button is pressed you can deactivate all buttons in that array expect the one that was clicked. For this you can even think about reducing the number of `@IBAction`s to 1 and connect all buttons to the same method and use the `sender` to filter out the one button you have to activate.

Comment: For your great answer. +1

Comment: @Krunal I think JD's answer is best (in theory) but for some reason he deleted it :/

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for your reply. All the buttons are now connected to the array. What do you mean with the `@IBAction` and the senders?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is the one mentioned before:

```
    zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
    tenPctButton.isSelected = false
    twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
    
    sender.isSelected = true
```

This option helps to save lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Give same button action to all the buttons  
 @IBAction func allButtonsActionsClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    button1.isSelected = false
    button2.isSelected = false
    button3.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true
    }
```